# CSS empty column but still shows up

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a system within my templating where if I put content in the "sidebars" then the sidebar will show and the main window content will be moved appropriately. If there is no content in the sidebar then it wont show.

```
 <div id="newcontainer">
    <div id="content">               
        <div id="sidebar-left">
        {% block left_sidebar %}
        {% endblock%}
        </div>
        <div id="sidebar-right">
        {% block right_sidebar %}
        {% endblock%}            
        </div>
        <div id="col-main">
        {% block content %}
        {% endblock%}
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is how far I have got with other users help:
**[JSFIDDLE LINK](http://jsfiddle.net/aBbtN/42/)**

However, as you can see I have put no content in the left column, but still the padding shows up! This is what I dont want, when there is no content in the sidebar I want it to disappear completely. What options do I have for this? I dont want to put the padding on the center box because when there are no sidebars I will be left with the padding on the center box still.

Comment: Why don't you just put margins on the sidebar *content* and remove the padding from the sidebar itself? That way if there's no content, there's no margin/padding.

Comment: Ok, so the sidebar acts as a wrap? I also found that setting "height: auto;" on the sidebars works but is this a bodge? http://jsfiddle.net/aBbtN/54/

Comment: Roddy, your answer is actually probably the most logical I didnt think of it. However, I cant award you this at the moment since its just a comment!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can, given a fairly modern browser, use the `:empty` pseudo-selector to target those empty elements:

```
#sidebar-left:empty,
#sidebar-right:empty {
    padding: 0;
    border-width: 0;
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/aBbtN/48/).

You could also, if you wrap the text in the columns with an element (in this case that of the right-column, with a `p`) in order that it can be targeted with CSS, you can use `margin` instead of `padding`:

```
#sidebar-left p,
#sidebar-right p {
    margin: 0 10px;
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/aBbtN/55/).

Also, if you move more of the styling to the child elements you can address the visible borders as well (though this has the consequence of the parent element not seeming to be its full, specified, height):

```
#sidebar-left p,
#sidebar-right p {
    padding: 0 10px;
    background-color: grey;
    border: 0 solid #000;
}

#sidebar-right p {
    border-left-width: 1px;
}

#sidebar-left p {
    border-right-width: 1px;
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/aBbtN/56/).

Comment: Thank you David, but I am after more compatibility than this solution offers http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/pseudoclass-empty

Comment: @JamesWillson: yeah, it does have that problem unfortunately. Also, updated with a slightly more cross-browser compatible approach (which doesn't deal with the remaining border, unfortunately).

Comment: I appreciate your long and detailed (updated) reply. Am I not better off instead putting the margins on the sidebar content and remove the padding from the sidebar itself as Roddy suggested?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you set a height. If you change `height: 80px;` to `max-height: 50px;` it will fix your problem

Or you can just not use a height if allowed